# Reactjs - parent, child action and functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs application - and I am breaking up a big component to have a child component. I've created a callback function in the child that will go back to the parent. When a checkbox is checked -- the child component does the callback and this goes back into the parent shell -- however I want to now jump out of the event callback and push the data to an original parent function.

my application kind of looks like this on a streamlined level.

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

    onSelect: function(value, flag){
     this.updateSelected(value, flag);
    }

    updateSelected: function(value, flag) {

        let array = this.state.selectedArray;

        array.push({"value": value, "flag": flag});
        this.setState({
            selectedArray: array
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child onSelect={this.changeHandler} />
                <span>{this.state.value}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    selectHandler: function(e) {
        this.props.onSelect(e.target.value, false);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <input type="checkbox" onSelect={this.selectHandler} />
        );
    }
});
```

but I can not just invoke the "this.updateSelected(value, flag);" as its inside the this scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ES6` syntax and JSX syntax instead of pure React API, that help you a lot to reduce this kind of error about scoping and become your code more readable, but If you even want to use that syntax, so you should bind the function once you pass down to the child component , you can do it like this:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

    onSelect: function(value, flag){
     this.updateSelected(value, flag);
    }

    updateSelected: function(value, flag) {

        let array = this.state.selectedArray;

        array.push({"value": value, "flag": flag});
        this.setState({
            selectedArray: array
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child onSelect={this.changeHandler.bind(this)} />
                <span>{this.state.value}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

as you can see adding the `.bind` method and passing as argument the context that you want your function execute, then once your function be invoked, the scope of that function will be the parent component instead of child component.

> Remember that this approach `bind` method could affect the improve of your component if your Parent component rerenders many times.

If you are using JSX syntax you should do something like

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  changeHandler = (value, flag) => {
    this.updateSelected(value, flag);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <Child onSelect={this.changeHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: let me check -- "class el extends React.Component" -- it written like this

Comment: @Rob are you using JSX syntax or React API `createClass` ?

Comment: its got jsx files

Comment: that bind in the child - worked -- yeah this is a complicated application -- trying to refactor

Comment: mmm I got it, so yeah the best you can do is to start using `class YourComponent extends React.Component` instead, and using arrow function to avoid using `bind`, I edited the answer.

Comment: yeah - that's what its using. I wasn't sure if I needed a bind - but yeah ok